# Use "Query Builder" to create a function allowing to take the average of values - Symfony

Tags: mysql, symfony, query-builder

I need help concerning the use of "Query Builder" in Symfony.

I would like to retrieve the values ​​of an attribute (Note) from one of my tables (Avis) in my database. After that, I would like to average all of his scores for display on my site.

For now I have the SQL query which achieves what I want :

```
SELECT AVG(avis.note) AS notetotal FROM avis
```

But afterwards, I don't understand what to do, or at least how "Query Builder" works

Comment: You can use QueryBuilder with Symfony, but it is from the Doctrine Project. Does you have create entity classes in your project? Like `App\Entity\Avis` ?

Comment: Yes of course. I even know that the Query Builder function must be carried out in the Avis Repository. But the problem is, I don't know how to do this function, because this is the first time I use "Query Builder" and I don't really understand how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the QueryBuilder you can build your queries step by step in a programmatically way, but its actualy only build the DQL wich you can get with `$queryBuilder->getDql()`. There are some cases where its easier to use the QueryBuilder instead of concatinate a long DQL query string.
There are two possible ways to build the query with the QueryBuilder. But for most cases its recommended to use plain DQL where ever you can, as its more readable.

First with the Expr Class

```php
$queryBuilder = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQueryBuilder('a');
$queryBuilder->select($queryBuilder->expr()->avg('a.note'))
        ->from(Avis::class, 'a');
$avg = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getSingleResult();

// $avg = [1 => (int) AVG]
```

or without Expr Class

```php
$queryBuilder = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQueryBuilder('a');
$queryBuilder->select('AVG(a.note) as notetotal')
        ->from(Avis::class, 'a');
$avg = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getSingleResult();

// $avg = ['notetotal' => (int) AVG]
```

The same in DQL

```php
$dql = 'SELECT AVG(a.note) AS notetotal FROM ' . Avis::class . ' a';
$avg = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQuery($dql)->execute();

// $avg = [0 => ['notetotal' => (int) AVG]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanations ! It is actually quite easy to understand!
So, I think I'm using DQL, because it's easier to understand. But suddenly in my Controller, in the return part, what part should I add? Because it is especially this part which blocks me, most often I get "variable does not exist" etc.

Comment: Please avoid adding follow-up question to your existing question. Mark it as resolved, then post a new question with the new error and the code of your controller ;)

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry.